How to narrow string representation of float when possible?
I look into std::format trying to make short std::string representation of floating point variable.
My problem is that I can't set width, since I don't know how many digits before decimal point. If I set precision, it prints zeroes even if they are the only trailing digits.
I guess this could be achieved somehow with width/precision/filling, etc., but can't see the way.
Let's say I want the string to fit in the specified fit_to if only possible; if not the string should take the minimum possible digits, preferring "100" to "1e2" or "1000" to 1e03" or "0.01" to "1e-2", etc.
Could this be achieved with std::format (or any other kind of std formatting) without manual conversion of every digit from float?
#include <iostream>

std::string to_string_shortest(float v, [[maybe_unused]] std::size_t fit_to = 4) {
    return std::format("{}", v);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(3.1415926f) << '\n';        // Want to have 3.14
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1e7f) << '\n';              // Want to have 1e+7 (1e7 acceptable)
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1e-7f) << '\n';             // Want to have 1e-7
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1.2345e20f) << '\n';        // Want to have 1e20
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1.2345e-20f) << '\n';       // Want to have 1e-20

    std::cout << to_string_shortest(3.1415926f, 8) << '\n';     // Want to have 3.141593
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(-3.1415926f, 8) << '\n';    // Want to have -3.14159
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1.2345e20f, 8) << '\n';     // Want to have 1.234e20
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1.2345e-20f, 8) << '\n';    // Want to have 1.23e-20

    std::cout << to_string_shortest(0.001f) << '\n';            // Want to keep as is
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1.0f) << '\n';              // Want to keep as is
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1e20f) << '\n';             // Want to keep as is
    std::cout << to_string_shortest(1e-20f) << '\n';            // Want to keep as is
}

Demo.

There are libraries that convert floating point values to the shortest possible string, for example google's double-conversion library. It's a non-trivial task, so AFAIK you're going to need a third party library.

Are you sure executed result you are proposing are correct? When I try implemented this actual results sometimes are looking more reasonable then your examples: https://godbolt.org/z/GfqEf7jje

@john, thank you for the hint, I glanced the sources, good way to go. Meanwhile I implemented my own version (took about 20 mins) with some extra requirements like ('M' and 'K' suffixes for million and thousand) which works just fine for my purposes, but I can't be sure that it works in all corner cases and I don't really like the resulting code with many if statements. Anyway, good enough for the moment; in case of issues, will port google's code. I am just surprised that std doesn't provide this out of the box.

@MarekR, sorry you lost me. I am looking into your demo and can't find cases when it produces more reasonable results than I provided in comments. Could you, please, pinpoint at least one particular example where you think that the test provides more readable and reasonable result than I provided in comments?

@PeteBecker, this is a kind of habit. I was in a way to write my own conversion function which might have crashed at any point. In this particular case I would prefer to have all buffers flushed before the crash to make sure that the output is on the screen. The habit comes from writing code which uses logs, file output, etc. If I expect the application to crash earlier, I would prefer std::endl. I know the difference, but don't you think that in this particular case (tiny sample) this verges nitpicking (with all respect and thankfulness to all your input to all my questions; no jokes!).

@DavisHerring, you missed my point. If you re-read my comment, you find that this habit is caused by "writing code which uses logs, file output, etc.", so I know the difference and it doesn't make any difference (intentional duplicate) here. Focus on this from PeteBecker was more than enough. Shouldn't we get more focused on the topic itself, do you have any input on the key part of the question? Any code could be optimized, but premature optimization is the root of all evil. Well, improved, to be precise here... With all respect to you, as well
